# How to create pop-up window containing filter options for a report

Tags: ms-access, popup, ms-access-2010, filtering

MS Access novice here with almost no VBA/SQL experience. I've created a database with tables, queries, forms, and reports that all function well together except a few select things I'm stuck on.

Purpose of changing to the below method: Currently, I have created three main report types, with different filter options for each report. AKA: there is a SEPARATE REPORT displaying each different filter option, even though the report contains the same root information. It'd be great to have one report that allows users to filter/group/sort multiple ways to streamline the reporting process.

I'd like to have a 'Filter' button on my Reports form that opens a pop-up window containing filter options via combo boxes. To clarify - the pop-up form has been created and I can easily add a 'Filter Options' button to the report form that opens the pop-up window.

The pop-up form has combo boxes with Control Sources related to the field names on the main table that the report pulls from, as well as buttons for 'Close', 'Apply Filters', and 'Clear Filters'.

What I need help with: getting the combo boxes to supply options as well as get the 'Apply Filters' button to actually work. The filter options need to pull from fields in one of the main tables, with no text entry allowed.

'Apply Filters' button needs to do the following:

- Apply filters per combo box selections. Needs to be OK for Users to leave filters blank if they choose.
- Gives User a preview of the report w/ applied filters

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  We are a group of students and professionals who help each other out with *specific* questions and issues.  What you're asking is much more complex.  Please come back with a *specific* question and we'll do our best.  For example, "I have FieldX in TableY that I'd like to use as the source for my combo box.  Here's the code I've tried but it's not working.  Can someone help?".  No one here is going to do your entire project for you, in fact there's a "Vote To Close" reason for that and your question will likely get closed.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to do is close the report and re-open it using the Filter and Preview options. Look into DoCmd.OpenReport. You will have to convert your filter to an SQL language filter based on what he user selects but everything else is pretty straightforward.

Comment: I may be a lost cause here, but how do you convert the filter to SQL?

Comment: You create a string as if it was a WHERE clause in SQL and pass it on to the OpenReport function. That does mean that you need at least rudimentary knowledge of the SQL language as well as Access VBA.

Comment: Maybe in the SQL of the report as in the record source of the design view with the selection type being the report you can add the other form's drop down selections as criteria of the SQL

Answer (score 0):

So the way I would work this is build a criteria into the form query with a parameter surrounding your popup form's combo box 
[image: ![QueryCriteria]

then in your form vba I'd write:

```
Private Sub Filter1_AfterUpdate()
     DoCmd.Close acReport, "Rpt2_FWItemsDue_AllSubs" 
     DoCmd.OpenReport "Rpt2_FWItemsDue_AllSubs", A_PREVIEW
     DoCmd.Maximize  
End Sub
```

assuming the name of the control is "Filter1" and the name of your form is "Rpt2_FWItemsDue_AllSubs" and "Filter1" filters the "FW_SubName" in the report.